# BEF - Multiselect option renders checkboxes instead select multiple

Tags: views, 8

I'm having issues with my VIEW filter, which has only 4 options and is set to **allow select multiple options**. Therefore **Better Exposed Filters** (BEF) renders options as checkboxes instead of html **select** tag. How can I override this behavior, to render options inside *(as it behaves when filter has 5+ options)*

```
<select multiple>
    <option>
    ...
</select>
```